# How to get an R script to run in parallel on a mosix cluster?

Tags: r, mosix

I am trying to re-create the example given in part 3 of [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4243301/), which performs a simple calculation across several instances managed by a cluster. The main calculation happens in this script, "sim.R":

```
# sim.R
# If the "batch" package has not been installed, run the line below:
# install.packages("batch", repos = "http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu")
seed <- 1000
n <- 50
nsim <- 10000
mu <- c(0, 0.5)
sd <- c(1, 1)
library("batch")

parseCommandArgs()
set.seed(seed)
pvalue <- rep(0,nsim)

for(i in 1:nsim) {
        X <- rnorm(n = n, mean = mu[1], sd = sd[1])
        Y <- rnorm(n = n, mean = mu[2], sd = sd[2])
        pvalue[i] <- t.test(X, Y)$p.value
}
power <- mean(pvalue <= 0.05)

out <- data.frame(seed = seed, nsim = nsim, n = n,
        mu = paste(mu, collapse = ","),
        sd = paste(sd, collapse = ","), power = power)
outfilename <- paste("res", seed, ".csv", sep = "")
print(out)
write.csv(out, outfilename, row.names = FALSE)
```

To run multiple, parallel instances of sim.R, there is another script "param-sim.R"

```
library("batch")
seed <- 1000
for(i in 1:10) {
        seed <- rbatch("sim.R", seed = seed, n = 25, mu = c(0, i / 10))
        rbatch.local.run() # My understanding from the linked paper is that this line will do nothing if the script is run on a mosix cluster and not locally.
}
```

To run this on a mosix cluster, I use the following command from the terminal:

```
R --vanilla --args RBATCH mosix < param-sim.R
```

I would expect this output to generate 10 .csv files, labeled res1000.csv - res1009.csv. Instead, here's what I get (I am running this command in an Ubuntu environment):

```
$ R --vanilla --args RBATCH mosix < param-sim.R

R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library("batch")
> seed <- 1000
> for(i in 1:10) {
+   seed <- rbatch("sim.R", seed = seed, n = 25, mu = c(0, i / 10))
+   rbatch.local.run()
+ }
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1000 n 25 mu "c(0,0.1)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1000 & 
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1001 n 25 mu "c(0,0.2)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1001 & 
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1002 n 25 mu "c(0,0.3)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1002 & 
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1003 n 25 mu "c(0,0.4)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1003 & nohup: 
redirecting stderr to stdout
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1004 n 25 mu "c(0,0.5)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1004 & 
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1005 n 25 mu "c(0,0.6)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1005 & 
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1006 n 25 mu "c(0,0.7)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1006 & 
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1007 n 25 mu "c(0,0.8)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1007 & 
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1008 n 25 mu "c(0,0.9)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1008 & 
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
nohup mosrun -e -b -q R --vanilla --args  seed 1009 n 25 mu "c(0,1)" < sim.R > sim.Rout1009 & 
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
> 
nohup: redirecting stderr to stdout
```

No .csv files are generated, and each of the output files (i.e. sim.Rout1000) contains identical information:

```
mosrun - MOSIX Version 4.3.4
Usage: mosrun [location-options] [program-options] {program} [args]...
       mosrun -S{maxjobs} [location-options] [program-options]
                                                {commands-file}[,{failed-file}]
       mosrun -R{filename} [-O{fd=filename}][,{fd2=fn2}]... [location-options]

       mosrun -I{filename}

  Location options - Node specification:
        -b                      try to start on 'best' available node
        -r{hostname}            start on given host
        -{a.b.c.d}              start on the node of given IP address
        -{n}                    start on given logical node number
        -h                      start on home node
  Other location options:
        -F                      do not fail if requested node is not available
        -L                      lock, disallow automatic migration
        -l                      unlock, allowing automatic migration
        -g                      disallow automatic freezing
        -G                      allow automatic freezing
        -m{mb}                  try to run only on nodes with >= mb free memory
        -A {minutes}            auto checkpoint interval in minutes (0-10000000)
        -N {max}                max. # of checkpoints before cycle (0-10000000)
  Program options:
        -e                      unsupported system calls produce -1/errno=ENOSYS
        -w                      as -e, but print warnings for unsupported calls
        -u                      unsupported system calls kill mosrun (default)
        -d {0-10000}            specify decay rate per second in parts of 10000
        -c                      consider program as a pure CPU job (ignore I/O)
        -n                      reverse '-c', so to include I/O considerations
        -C{filename}            test given checkpoint file
        -X{/directory}          declare private directory
        -z                      program arguments start at argument #0 (not #1)
```

Which leads me to think that the program never ran or entered a cluster queue. I have also checked the system processes with the "top" command, and uncovered nothing. For the record, I have been able to successfully run simple C++ programs on a mosix cluster.

Have I missed a key detail to allow this program to work?

Comment: What happens if you move the `rbatch.local.run()` outside the loop?

Comment: @MrFlick I get the same output, although it ends with:  rbatch.local.run()
rbatch.local.run: no commands have been batched.
NULL
>